# Tree-Structure to wide Table in R

Tags: r, dataframe, transform

How can i transform a Tree-Struckture Dataframe

[image]

to a wide Table like this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.tree)
```

It is easier to work directly with names rather than IDs in `data.tree`, thus we do a self join to get parent names in the same table.

```
df <- merge(df, df, by.x = "ParentId", by.y = "Id",
            suffixes = c("", ".Parent"))


tree <- FromDataFrameNetwork(df[c("Name.Parent", "Name")])

#                 levelName
# 1  Biota                 
# 2   ¦--Plantea           
# 3   ¦   ¦--Tree          
# 4   ¦   ¦   ¦--Bonsai    
# 5   ¦   ¦   °--Apple-Tree
# 6   ¦   °--Flower        
# 7   °--Animal            
# 8       ¦--Bear          
# 9       ¦--Fish          
# 10      °--Bird 

ToDataFrameTypeCol(tree)

#   level_1 level_2 level_3    level_4
# 1   Biota Plantea    Tree     Bonsai
# 2   Biota Plantea    Tree Apple-Tree
# 3   Biota Plantea  Flower       <NA>
# 4   Biota  Animal    Bear       <NA>
# 5   Biota  Animal    Fish       <NA>
# 6   Biota  Animal    Bird       <NA>
```

---

With data:

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Id, ~Name, ~ParentId,
  1, "Biota", NA,
  2, "Plantea", 1,
  3, "Animal", 1,
  4, "Tree", 2,
  5, "Flower", 2,
  6, "Bear", 3,
  7, "Fish", 3,
  8, "Bird", 3,
  9, "Bonsai", 4,
  10, "Apple-Tree", 4,
)
```